# pyspark create a dataframe for each row some of the column values need to be set to be 1

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create an pyspark dataframe. I know all the column names. For each row with an id, only a set of the columns need to have value 1.

For example, if the users clicks on a website is known. user1 may clicked url2 and 3. user2 clicked url1 and 3. Then the input dataframe is

> id|urlClicked|
>
> --+----+
>
> u1 |url2
>
> u1 |url3
>
> u2 |url1
>
> u2 |url3

....
this goes on for all the other users.

Then, I know that the output dataframe will have 4 columns: id, url1, url2, url3 etc..

- In the first row (id = u1), only [url2,url3] is clicked. Thus url2 and url3 columns needs to be set to be 1.
- In the second row (id = u2), only [col1,col3] is clicked, Thus url1 and url3 columns needs to be set to be 1. This goes on until the last user is taken into account.

The end results will be:

id|url1|url2|url3

--+----+----+----

u1 | 0  | 1  | 1

u2 | 1  | 0  | 1

u3 | 1  | 1  | 1

and many other rows follow the same logic.

Comment: Please read [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) and try to provide us with a small sample of your inputs. It's unclear from your question how the row ID and input lists are specified.

Comment: Hope the question is clear now.